# How to use a picture from ethernet camera with right type of variable for nerual network

Tags: python, opencv, fast-ai

I tried to capture a picture which I take with an ethernet camera for my code.
I would like to load my image in my trained model. Before I used the camera, I load a local image in the three outcomment lines.

But when I use the camera right now, I get following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'apply_tfms'.
```

Before that I tried to convert the image from the camera from an array to a tensor with  `torch.from_numpy(image)`, because when I checked the older code, `img` was a tensor type too.

Here is the code snippet:

```
from fastai import *
from fastai.vision import *
from fastai.callbacks.hooks import *
from fastai.utils.mem import *
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv2
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def acc_camvid(input, target):
    target = target.squeeze(1)
    mask = target != void_code
    #print(mask)
    return (input.argmax(dim=1)[mask]==target[mask]).float().mean()

learn=load_learner(r'C:\Users\model')
    
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.1.110/LiveImage.jpg')
    
r, image = cap.read()
plt.imshow(image)
image=torch.from_numpy(image) 

#fn= r'C:\Users\image' 
#  img = open_image(fn); img.shape
#_,img_hr,b = learn.predict(img)
_,img_hr,b = learn.predict(image)
```

I hope you understand my problem. If not please ask. I appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: What's that `learn=load_learner`? Provide that part of the code.

Comment: I import my trained NN with `load_learner`. https://docs.fast.ai/learner.html#load_learner

Comment: That's actually more about `fast-ai` than `pytorch`.